# SQL to LINQ converter required, any idea?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, converters

We have [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) which is great for testing Linq expressions targeting database.

Can any one recommend "free ware" tool, that could help us convert

- "Sql Queries" to LINQ expressions

and why you recommend it?

NOTE: Please keep in mind, we use c#.

Comment: I think linqpad is the best tool

Comment: @anishmarokey - Linqpad does not do what he says he wants to do.

Comment: +1 for mentioning LINQPad. Great for quick "will it work?" spikes, even ones not using LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as tool, [Randy Minder's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103747/sql-to-linq-converter/2103762#2103762) of [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) is the only direct tool I've seen.

That being said, the Visual Basic team did a [very good series showing how to go from SQL to LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/tags/Converting+SQL+to+LINQ/default.aspx).  This walks through what it takes to learn how to do the conversion yourself.  Converting from VB's LINQ to C# LINQ is very easy (most of the statements are nearly identical in LINQ), so it's a good way to learn how to do this, even for C# developers.

Even if you're using a tool, I'd recommend trying to understand the concepts - tools don't always produce the best code.  Knowing how to do this yourself is very valuable.

Comment: Thanks mate, point noted. Reason behind using a tool is to convert already in use large amount of sql queries with LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

The only tool I am aware of that will do this is [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/). It is not free, but can be purchased for under $50 I believe. It has worked very well for me.

Comment: Are there any know problems to install linqer on Vista. We are having problems for some reason.

Comment: I've never tried. I only have it installed on XP. If such a problem exists, there should be something stated about this on their website.